# Nexus search apparently limiting snapshot search results in proxy repository

Tags: nexus

I am running Nexus 2.3.1-01.  I define a proxy repository that proxies snapshots from an upstream nexus instance.  When I browse the remote repository associated with this proxy, I can see the snapshot artifact of interest.  However, when I search for all versions of this artifact in the Nexus admin web ui, older versions of the snapshot artifact appear, but not the more recent versions of interest.  Yet those more recent versions are clearly visible when I browse the remote.

I've struggled with this for a few hours, and have tried expiring the proxy cache, rebuilding the index, and repairing the index.  This is a fresh installation of Nexus, so a damaged index seems unlikely.

Might someone provide some guidance on what I can try next?  I should add that my mvn clients cannot resolve the snapshot dependency of interest either.

Comment: I would add that the following also obtain on the proxy configuration:  Repository Policy==Snapshot and Download Remote Indexes==True.  The proxy is also included in the Public Repositories group, but I don't think that comes into play until my mvn client, which points to this group as a mirror of the world, requests an artifact at the Group URL.  I also have a route defined that should route the artifact request to a group of repositories that does in fact contain the proxy.  But, as with the group URL, I *think* the route only plays with a mvn client request.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  My mistake, of course.

The POM my test project was using did not have a  clause in it pointing to an appropriate repository.  The only hint of a repository was in my settings.xml file, and that repository was in a  clause, which I want, but which is not sufficient.

What was the final hint?  When I dumped the effective POM (mvn help:effective-pom), I saw the only repository configured was Maven Central.  And snapshots were disabled.  I (actually a coworker) realized that this single repository could not bootstrap the ability to resolve snapshots.

So I added a repository clause to my POM, enabled snapshots on it, and now everything, releases and snapshots resolve fine.  Of course, the repository has to be setup to hand back releases and snapshots, but I already that part of my Nexus config right.